# Does PHP have built-in debugging logging like Ruby on Rails logger.info() to a development.log file?

Tags: php

Does PHP have built-in debugging logging like Ruby on Rails logger.info() to a development.log file?

With PHP I'd like to look "under the hood" to see what's going on... pages served, query string values, etc.

I've Googled a bunch but can't find anything.

(I'm trying to port a web app from RoR to PHP because I need more execution speed.)

Comment: Have you profiled the app to make sure that your app really is limited by the language's execution speed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP has

- [`error_log`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) — *Sends an error message to the web server's error log, a TCP port or to a file* and
- [`trigger_error`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) — *Generates a user-level error/warning/notice message*

which you can use to trigger and log the [predefined error types](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php), e.g.

```
trigger_error( "Custom Warning", E_USER_WARNING );
```

Third party libraries exists with

- [PEAR Log](http://pear.php.net/package/Log/redirected) and
- [Zend_Log](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.log.html)

You can configure various destinations to log to. Usage is via an OO interface:

```
$logger->log('Informational message', Zend_Log::INFO);
```

and there is also the Log4J inspired

- [Log4PHP](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/index.html)

Apart from that there is [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) and [Zend Debugger](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads). There is also a PECL extension with [Advanced PHP Debugger (APD)](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php)

Comment: +1 for mentioning xdebug -- it changed the way I develop for PHP.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question wasn't clear.  I'm not looking for a "log4" utility, but an automatic diagnostic.

Comment: @Pete I am not familiar with what logger does in Ruby. Sorry if my answer contains suggestions not applicable. Judging by the [API docs for Logger in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Logger.html) I'd say you are either looking for `error_log` or the PEAR or Zend package. XDebug and Zend Debugger are sophisticated debuggers that let you profile your code, step it through it with breakpoints and so on.