# Does PHP have automatic built-in diagnostic page logging like that built into Ruby on Rails? (as opposed to log4j-type logging libraries)

Tags: php

That shows:

1. page execution time duration
2. query string and form parameters
3. SQL activity

For a *behind the scenes* look at page execution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does PHP have built-in debugging logging like Ruby on Rails logger.info() to a development.log file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953217/does-php-have-built-in-debugging-logging-like-ruby-on-rails-logger-info-to-a-de) - I think those two should be merged, since this one is just a refined version of the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare RoR with php (framework vs language?).
You can compare Ruby with php.
And you can compare RoR with Symfony.
And yes, symfony provides you with a debug toolbar with the 3 things you mentioned and more...
So does [Magento](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RMEOMHMM2Q)

Answer (score 0):

Page execution time can come from Apache's `access_log` (as will `GET` request parameters), but there's no automatic logging for `POST` data or SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about built-in solution but here is nice profiler:

- [Quick PHP Profiler](http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/)

[image]