# I want to retrieve all API calls history from docusign

Tags: laravel-8, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk

I tried to retrieve all API Calls history from docusign and later on want to list it on my website in laravel but I can't achieve it.

Can anyone suggests me, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Are you storing each api request anywhere like log file or in db? Or any specific tool

Comment: @Yogendra I want all information regarding api calls like envelope id, trace token, etc

Comment: Checkout this post. Is it answer of your question
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994159/logging-api-calls

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done programmatically.
You can only get the last 50 API calls in the web UI.

Instructions - https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-how-to-use-api-logs

Video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJYTDcc7cZw